# Maintaining application level data privacy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is it possible to have application level data privacy in Hyperlegder Fabric v2.2

We have the first network (as referenced in the fabric-samples) in place (Org1 and Org2 with peer0 and peer1 each). I am aware that data privacy can be ensured between 2 organizations using Private Data Collections. Looking at the case where peers in the network can run multiple user applications, consider that, there is app1 and app2 connected to the network via peer0 belonging to Org1. The cause for concern is that despite using private data collections, app1 could access the private data logged by app2 in Org1 private data collection. Is there a way in hyperledger fabric to ensure privacy between apps connected to the network via the same peer.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

You can develop your own authorization routines at smart contract level so that read related operations only return data to authorized users. This way you prevent other clients from accessing data through read operations, but the data is not protected from the peers themselves.

You can also encrypt your data in your client before sending it in a transaction. You can use your own Fabric certificate to encrypt data via ECIES or ECDH encryption schemas (or use any other encryption schema you want). But this way the contract is not going to be able to interpret your data. It will be only able to store it and return it...

In other cases, you may be interested in storing your data in your own private storage system outside Fabric and save only a hash of the data in the channel state as a proof that can be used later if necessary for whatever it is intended to.

These are things you can do to preserve privacy at user level. You can think of other solutions. But Fabric does not provide specific ways to do it. From a blockchain point of view, it is difficult to preserve data privacy at user-level while peers try to reach consensus over that data.